# How to delete only few values from a sql table output

Tags: sql-server

[image]

If you notice, I am just keeping the first three blocks of a row same and deleting the others as they are same but not deleting the entire row as the balance qty keeps on changing.  I want the first entire row to be retained, however succeeding rows should have only balance qty output for the part no , product descry and weight
Can someone please help me in suggesting a query in Microsoft SQL where I get an output shown in table 2 from table 1 output which I am getting through a query

Comment: I cannot see any image

Comment: Can you click on enter the image decription here @user1443098

Comment: Use an SSRS report for that. There, hiding duplicates is a piece of cake.

Answer (score 0):

This is really a presentation-level question.  I'd never do it in SQL, not that it's impossible.  Look up the [LAG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql) function.  you can use that to look at the previous row's description and set it to blank if equal.

Comment: I hope it doesn't delete the entire row , if it sees just one similar entry @user1443098